# Android Progress Dialog not showing in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, progressdialog

Someone please check my codes. My progress dialog just appears and dismisses so quickly before I could even see it. Its suppose to show a progress dialog during the download process. But my progress dialog dismisses before my image loads.

```
public class SingleImageViewActivity  extends SherlockActivity {

        // XML node keys
    static final String KEY_TITLE = "title";
    static final String KEY_ARTIST = "artist";  
    static final String KEY_THUMB_URL = "thumb_url";
    static final String KEY_BIG_URL = "big_url";
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    String title;
    String artist;
    //String image_url;
    String big_image_url;
    ImageView view;
    Intent intent;
    Context context;
    ShareActionProvider mShareActionProvider;
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.single_view_item);
            getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            //checkInternetConnection();

            new loadSingleView().execute();
            view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.single_image);    

        }

    public class loadSingleView extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SingleImageViewActivity.this);
                pDialog.setTitle("Connect to Server");
                pDialog.setMessage("This process can take a few seconds to a few minutes, depending on your Internet Connection Speed.");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(false);
                pDialog.show();
            }
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
                // updating UI from Background Thread


                Intent in = getIntent();

                //image_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_THUMB_URL);
                big_image_url = in.getStringExtra(KEY_BIG_URL);
                title = in.getStringExtra(KEY_TITLE);
                artist = in.getStringExtra(KEY_ARTIST);

                SingleViewImageLoader imgLoader = new SingleViewImageLoader(getApplicationContext());

                imgLoader.DisplayImage(big_image_url, view);
                return null;

                        }
            @Override       
            protected void onPostExecute(String args) {
                // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
                 TextView lblName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_title);
                    TextView lblCost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.name_artist);



                    lblName.setText(title);
                    lblCost.setText(artist);

                    ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
                    ab.setTitle(title);
                    ab.setSubtitle(artist);




                pDialog.dismiss();


            }


    }
```

SingleViewImageLoader.class

```
public class SingleViewImageLoader {

    MemoryCache memoryCache=new MemoryCache();
    FileCache fileCache;
    private Map<ImageView, String> imageViews=Collections.synchronizedMap(new WeakHashMap<ImageView, String>());
    ExecutorService executorService; 

    public SingleViewImageLoader(Context context){
        fileCache=new FileCache(context);
        executorService=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    }

   final int stub_id = R.drawable.no_image;
    public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        imageViews.put(imageView, url);
        Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);
        if(bitmap!=null)
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        else
        {
            queuePhoto(url, imageView);
            imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);

        }
    }

    private void queuePhoto(String url, ImageView imageView)
    {
        PhotoToLoad p=new PhotoToLoad(url, imageView);
        executorService.submit(new PhotosLoader(p));
    }

    private Bitmap getBitmap(String url) 
    {
        File f=fileCache.getFile(url);

        //from SD cache
        Bitmap b = decodeFile(f);
        if(b!=null)
            return b;

        //from web
        try {
            Bitmap bitmap=null;
            URL imageUrl = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)imageUrl.openConnection();
            conn.setConnectTimeout(30000);
            conn.setReadTimeout(30000);
            conn.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
            InputStream is=conn.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(f);
            Utils.CopyStream(is, os);
            os.close();
            bitmap = decodeFile(f);
            return bitmap;
        } catch (Exception ex){
           ex.printStackTrace();
           return null;
        }
    }

    //decodes image and scales it to reduce memory consumption
    private Bitmap decodeFile(File f){
        try {
            //decode image size
            BitmapFactory.Options o = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
            BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f),null,o);

            //Find the correct scale value. It should be the power of 2.
            final int REQUIRED_SIZE=500;
            int width_tmp=o.outWidth, height_tmp=o.outHeight;
            int scale=1;
            while(true){
                if(width_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE || height_tmp/2<REQUIRED_SIZE)
                    break;
                width_tmp/=2;
                height_tmp/=2;
                scale*=2;
            }

            //decode with inSampleSize
            BitmapFactory.Options o2 = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            o2.inSampleSize=scale;
            return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f), null, o2);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {}
        return null;
    }

    //Task for the queue
    private class PhotoToLoad
    {
        public String url;
        public ImageView imageView;
        public PhotoToLoad(String u, ImageView i){
            url=u; 
            imageView=i;
        }
    }

    class PhotosLoader implements Runnable {
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        PhotosLoader(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
            this.photoToLoad=photoToLoad;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            Bitmap bmp=getBitmap(photoToLoad.url);
            memoryCache.put(photoToLoad.url, bmp);
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;
            BitmapDisplayer bd=new BitmapDisplayer(bmp, photoToLoad);
            Activity a=(Activity)photoToLoad.imageView.getContext();
            a.runOnUiThread(bd);
        }
    }

    boolean imageViewReused(PhotoToLoad photoToLoad){
        String tag=imageViews.get(photoToLoad.imageView);
        if(tag==null || !tag.equals(photoToLoad.url))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    //Used to display bitmap in the UI thread
    class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable
    {
        Bitmap bitmap;
        PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;
        public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p){bitmap=b;photoToLoad=p;}
        public void run()
        {
            if(imageViewReused(photoToLoad))
                return;

            if(bitmap!=null)
                photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
          else
              photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);

        }
    }

    public void clearCache() {
        memoryCache.clear();
        fileCache.clear();
    }



}
```

Comment: what is SingleViewImageLoader?

Comment: here you are. I've edited my codes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its Because of Image Loader Class also use thread to show image, so it runs in background and your onPostExecute() Method is called and dismiss the Progress Dialog.

Comment: You mean there is nothing i can do?

Comment: Yes, Set your image without asynctask. Because your image loader class also use thread to show image . So need AsyncTask Class .

Comment: yes you can't because in image loader class there is no progress dialog.

Comment: got it. I guess i will show an image without using imageloader.

Comment: I'll accept your answer. But i'm locked for 5 mins for this question. Will give you a credit soon . Thanks by the way

Comment: I use AsyncTask to get google place info from google. Since that is networking I dont have a choise but to use a background thread. Is there a way I can use a ProgressDialog? I played with it for a few mins but had problems getting it to show.

Comment: Jason Crosby, I think you should open a new question to avoid confusion.